# Copy Subset of Rows in Database Tables from One Database to Another

Tags: mysql, sql, records

I have a productions Database with exact same schema as test database. The schema consists of more than 100 tables and its a typical relational database schema meaning that Foreign Keys are extensively used. What I need to achieve is to copy a subset of data e.g. All employees with employee ID > 100 from one database to another. Along with populating Employee table I also want that all the other tables referring to this table should also get populated. E.g. All personal detail of Employee ID 101 should get populated in Employee Table but also the check IN and Checkout record of employee 101 should be copied in LogInOut table. Task table should also get record all of task tasked assigned to Employee 101. Please help!

Comment: Change your FKs to `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Import the full data set. And delete everything with ID <= 100.

Comment: I would become quite an exercise if I were to import data of only 100 employees. I would first have to import data of all the employees, which would be in GBs.

Comment: So how many rows would that be which you want to export?

Comment: It varies from the nature of problem. Typically some hundreds of Rows are good enough. Now I can populate one table by limiting on Employee ID, but I do not get data that correlates to these employees

Comment: The selection criteria can be as simple as getting all employees between id 100 and 200, but it can also be a complex criteria e.g. all the employees that have worked overtime, or all the employees with Mr. X as supervisor.

Answer (score 1):

Use [SELECT INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html) to export the limited dataset in a CSV file.

Something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE ID > 100
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/employees.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Do the same for the other tables.

Then import them to your dev database using [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Comment: This will get me records for only one table. I was see if there is any way I can populate all the three tables in one go.

Comment: @Abdul What is the problem in writing three queries. I'd understand it, if it were 20 tables.

Comment: Before import use SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; so you don't have to worry about the order that data should be loaded. After you have finished re-enable with SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;